# Sonata Admin: How to skip or remove dashboard based on a role?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a couple of roles that only manage one type of entity. Landing the users on the dashboard and having them click into the entity section seems redundant.

Is there a way that the dashboard can be removed and an alternate default landing page can be set based on the role?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new service and override isGranted method from Sonata:

.yml

```
custom.sonata.security.handler.role:
    class: AdminBundle\Security\Handler\CustomRoleSecurityHandler
    arguments:
        - @security.token_storage
        - @security.authorization_checker
        - [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]
        - %security.role_hierarchy.roles%
```

.php

```
class CustomRoleSecurityHandler extends RoleSecurityHandler
{
    protected $securityContext;

    protected $superAdminRoles;

    protected $roles;
    /**
    * @var TokenStorageInterface
    */
    private $tokenStorageInterface;

    /**
    * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorageInterface
    * @param AuthorizationCheckerInterface $securityContext
    * @param array $superAdminRoles
    * @param $roles
    */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorageInterface, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $securityContext, array $superAdminRoles, $roles)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->superAdminRoles = $superAdminRoles;
        $this->roles           = $roles;
        $this->tokenStorageInterface = $tokenStorageInterface;
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function isGranted(AdminInterface $admin, $attributes, $object = null)
    {

        if (!is_array($attributes)) {
            $attributes = array($attributes);
        }

        foreach ($attributes as $pos => $attribute) {
            $attributes[$pos] = sprintf($this->getBaseRole($admin), $attribute);
        }

        $user = $this->tokenStorageInterface->getToken()->getUser();
        // ... check user role and do your stuff
    }

}
```